# How to serve binary (bytea) data from postgres using node?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, audio, mp3, pg-promise

I'm testing out postgres binary abilities by storing some mp3 data in a table.  I've read you're supposed to store them in an external filesystem like S3, but for various reasons I don't want to do that right now. 
So, for now I'd like to test storing files in the db.  The mp3 files are TTS mp3 files from a third-party and I've stored them in a postgres table.  This is working ok. But how do I serve them to the client?  In other words:

1. client http requests the files.
2. node requests (pg-promise) the records (one or many).
3. the data arrives from db to node in binary format.
4. ??? Do I have to convert it to a mp3 file before sending? Can I send the binary file directly?  Which would be better?
5. client receives file(s)
6. client queues files in order for playing audio.

My main question is whether I need to convert the binary record I received from postgres before sending, and how to do that?

Comment: I have a node server using express.

Comment: What I meant - you configure your server to either support binary streaming or not, and then you implement the HTTP server + client accordingly.